# rust “array struct” for constant length arrays

Tags: arrays, rust, struct, types

For 3D-modelling based on triangles, I use a C struct like

```rust
pub struct Point {
    pub x: f32,
    pub y: f32,
    pub z: f32,
};
```

and tuple struct like

```rust
pub struct Triangle (
    pub Point,
    pub Point,
    pub Point,
);
```

Algorithms based on triangles often have to iterate all points of a triangle. I can do this with

```rust
for point in [ triangle.0, triangle.1, triangle.2 ].iter() { … }
```

but I imagine that the conversion from Triangle to array will always cost some runtime, and I do not think this is an elegant idiom anyway. I would prefer if I could use a kind of type that I might call “array structs” of the form

```rust
pub struct Triangle [pub Point; 3];
```

which would itself implement `iter` and thus allow

```rust
for point in triangle.iter() { … }
```

I know that such “array struct” syntax is not available. So what would be a best practice idiom for the situation where a named type should essentially hold an array of one basic element type where the length of the array is known and fixed at compile time?

Comment: Do you mean `pub struct Triangle([Point; 3])`?

Comment: aka the newtypes pattern

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/new_types.html

Comment: As a note, you might want something more like `pub struct Polygon(Vec<Point>)` so you get more mileage out of this unless you're specifically optimizing for triangles. If you are optimizing for triangles, you may want to look at the memory footprint, and potentially have it defined as something with `x: [f32;3]`, etc. so it's more compact.

Comment: @tadman: `pub struct Triangle([Point; 3]);` implies that during initialisation and later access, I would always have to refer to struct member with suffix`.0`. If possible, I would like to avoid this.

Comment: You can make your types virtually transparent if you want to using tools like [`impl AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html), something containers like `Rc` do. Note you never have to call `.0` on an `Rc`. Keep in mind you may not want to directly expose traits, you might want a slight layer of abstraction here, as in `impl IntoIterator<Point>` instead, giving you more freedom to store the internals more efficiently, for example, something you might do specifically for `Triangle&`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have tiny arrays like less than 10-12 elements, it wouldn't cause a lot of problems because compiler unrolls loop and removes array as well by using direct copies from triangle.

See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,selection:(endColumn:18,endLineNumber:15,positionColumn:18,positionLineNumber:15,selectionStartColumn:18,selectionStartLineNumber:15,startColumn:18,startLineNumber:15),source:%27%23%5Bderive(Clone,+Copy)%5D%0Apub+struct+Point%7B%0A++++pub+x:+f32,+pub+y:+f32,+pub+z:+f32%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Clone,+Copy)%5D%0Apub+struct+Triangle+(%0A++++pub+Point,%0A++++pub+Point,%0A++++pub+Point,%0A)%3B%0A%0Apub+fn+update_triangles(triangle:+%26Triangle,+process:+fn(Point))%7B%0A++++for+point+in+%5B+triangle.0,+triangle.1,+triangle.2+%5D.iter()+%7B+%0A++++++++process(*point)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Apub+fn+update_triangles_inline(%0A++++triangle:+%26Triangle,+process:+fn(Point)%0A)%7B%0A++++process(triangle.0)%3B%0A++++process(triangle.1)%3B%0A++++process(triangle.2)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Rust+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:42.18941996092467,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:r1700,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,libs:!(),options:%27-Copt-level%3D3%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+rustc+1.70.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:32.883854902479285,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27clang+16.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+rustc+1.70.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:24.926725136596044,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

For example, this code:

```rust
pub fn update_triangles(triangle: &Triangle, process: fn(Point)){
    for point in [ triangle.0, triangle.1, triangle.2 ].iter() { 
        process(*point);
    }
}
```

converts to this asm:

```
example::update_triangles:
        push    r15
        push    r14
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     rbx, rsi
        mov     r14, rdi
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi + 8]
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 8], eax
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp], rax
        mov     r15, rsp
        mov     rdi, r15
        call    rsi
        mov     eax, dword ptr [r14 + 20]
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 8], eax
        mov     rax, qword ptr [r14 + 12]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp], rax
        mov     rdi, r15
        call    rbx
        mov     eax, dword ptr [r14 + 32]
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 8], eax
        mov     rax, qword ptr [r14 + 24]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp], rax
        mov     rdi, r15
        call    rbx
        add     rsp, 16
        pop     rbx
        pop     r14
        pop     r15
        ret
```

This may be not true for larger types and arrays though.

Another option is to implement iterator for your type:

```rust
impl Triangle {
    fn points(&'_ self)->impl Iterator<Item=Point> + '_ {
        (0..3).map(move|i|
            match i {
                0 => self.0,
                1 => self.1,
                2 => self.2,
                _ => unreachable!(),
            }
        )
    }
}

pub fn update_triangles(triangle: &Triangle, process: fn(Point)){
    for point in triangle.points() { 
        process(point);
    }
}
```

In this case, it generates unrolled loop without extra memory usage too: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:30,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:13,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:30,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:13),source:%27%23%5Bderive(Clone,+Copy)%5D%0Apub+struct+Point%7B%0A++++pub+x:+f32,+pub+y:+f32,+pub+z:+f32%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Clone,+Copy)%5D%0Apub+struct+Triangle+(%0A++++pub+Point,%0A++++pub+Point,%0A++++pub+Point,%0A)%3B%0A%0Aimpl+Triangle+%7B%0A++++fn+points(%26!%27_+self)-%3Eimpl+Iterator%3CItem%3DPoint%3E+%2B+!%27_+%7B%0A++++++++(0..3).map(move%7Ci%7C%0A++++++++++++match+i+%7B%0A++++++++++++++++0+%3D%3E+self.0,%0A++++++++++++++++1+%3D%3E+self.1,%0A++++++++++++++++2+%3D%3E+self.2,%0A++++++++++++++++_+%3D%3E+unreachable!!(),%0A++++++++++++%7D%0A++++++++)%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Apub+fn+update_triangles(triangle:+%26Triangle,+process:+fn(Point))%7B%0A++++for+point+in+triangle.points()+%7B+%0A++++++++process(point)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Rust+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:42.18941996092467,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:r1700,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,libs:!(),options:%27-Copt-level%3D3%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:12,endLineNumber:31,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:12,selectionStartLineNumber:31,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+rustc+1.70.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:32.883854902479285,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27clang+16.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+rustc+1.70.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:24.926725136596044,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

You need to be careful with that though because if compiler would fail with optimization, you would get more branches than when using array which may lead to slower code execution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `struct` I have found out I can use a named type like this:

```rust
type Triangle = [ Point; 3 ];
```

Then I can loop over `triangle.iter()`, and even simpler without explicit `iter`:

```rust
for point in triangle { … }
```

(Dropping `iter()` would have been possible in the code in the question, too.)

Comment: The downside of using `type` instead of `struct` is that I cannot simply write `impl Triangle { fn new … }` but an additional trait is needed to hold the functions. (See `rustc --explain E0390`.)